# Design the coefficients of Wide-band FIR filters

Tags: matlab, finite-impulse-response

It will be a great help if someone could share a content/tutorial about how to design the coefficients of Wide-band FIR Filters.

Comment: Hello Joseph, welcome to the DSP Stackexchange! Could you elaborate a bit more on your question to narrow the scope of the question down, for example by stating your application and its limitations? There is a range of available design routines which may be of interest to you.

Comment: You can also see this [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45858/determining-the-filter-coefficients-of-an-fir-filter). It is *not* about _"Wide-band"_ FIR filters per se, but is none the less about "calculating the coefficients of an FIR Filter".

Comment: p.s. I maybe wrong, but the better term would be - _"calculating the coefficients of a wideband FIR filter"_ rather than _"designing ..."_.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands your question appears to be quite broad, so the answer depends largely on your application and level of knowledge.

If you have no prior experience, you might want to consider picking up a book about digital signal processing, e.g.

- [Digital Signal Processing by John G. Proakis and Dimitry Manolakis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873741)

which may be available in your local library.

For digital filters specifically, there are great resources available online such as this free book:

- [INTRODUCTION TO DIGITAL FILTERS WITH AUDIO APPLICATIONS by JULIUS O. SMITH III](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/)

There is also the Cookbook for audio EQ biquad filters by RBJ which you should also check out, found for example [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/) (although i cannot find the original link right now).